# Qt5: как встроить модальный диалог в приложение

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть модальный для всего приложения диалог, который позволяет пользователю залогиниться для дальнейшего использования приложения. Как теперь его правильно включить в приложение?
Попробовал так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    LoginDialog * ldlg = new LoginDialog();
    if(ldlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
        w.show();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Но оно естессно не работает.
Есть так же вопрос относительно того, что должно возвращать окошко диалога.
Я так понял, когда всё хорошо, надо пустить сигнал accepted

```
void LoginDialog::on_pushButton_ld_login_clicked()
{
    Ops * temp = new Ops(nullptr, nullptr, ui->lineEdit_Login->text(), ui->lineEdit_Pass->text());
    if(opLogin.Check(*temp)) emit accepted();
    else emit rejected();
}
```

Но опять же, я похоже понял что-то не так.
Как правильно дать из него положительный и отрицательный выхлоп?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо сигнала accepted попробуйте использовать метод [QDialog::accept](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept):

```
void LoginDialog::on_pushButton_ld_login_clicked()
{
    Ops * temp = new Ops(nullptr, nullptr, ui->lineEdit_Login->text(), ui->lineEdit_Pass->text());
    if(opLogin.Check(*temp)) accept();
    else reject();
}
```

Можно также возвращать из диалога произвольный код методом [QDialog::done](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done)